# How to calculate multivariate normal probability distribution function with mean and cov saved in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, distribution

I'm a beginner to Python. It would be appreciated if anybody could help me.

I have an array `O` in which the first and second columns correspond to the mean and cov of three (one for each row) multivariate normal random variables, respectively.

I'd like to compute the probability distribution function using SciPy's `multivariate_normal.pdf()` for a given number (for example `x = 2.5`) with these three means and covs.  The result should be saved in an array `alpha` with the shape of `1 * 3`.

I need to use `multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=m, cov=co)`. My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

alpha = np.zeros((1, 3))
O = np.array([[3.8, 0.01], [1, 1], [2, 0.5]])

def c_emission(x, m, co):
    return multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=m, cov=co)

alpha[0, :] = c_emission(2.5, O[:, 0], O[:, 1])
```

My problem is that `c_emission(2.5, O[:, 0], O[:, 1])` is a scalar instead of a vector.

Comment: I don't recommend using `O` as a variable name since it looks so much like `0` (zero).